# PerfMon reports in JMeter using non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter

Im running load test using JMeter 5.1.1 in non-gui mode, And I need to capture server's RAM & CPU utilization separately during the test execution.

So that I kept **PerfMon Metrics Collector** plugin inside the Jmeter's test plan (CPU and RAM separately) and started the *Server Agent* in the hosted server.

And when I start executing load test in non-gui, I can get below mentioned tets connection commands in the command prompt window,

```
INFO    2019-07-10 12:03:46.485 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444
INFO    2019-07-10 12:03:47.486 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444
INFO    2019-07-10 12:03:47.486 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.3 started

INFO    2019-07-10 12:05:21.595 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection
INFO    2019-07-10 12:05:21.595 [kg.apc.p] (): Yep, we received the 'test' command
INFO    2019-07-10 12:05:21.611 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: memory:
INFO    2019-07-10 12:05:21.627 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection
INFO    2019-07-10 12:05:21.627 [kg.apc.p] (): Yep, we received the 'test' command
INFO    2019-07-10 12:05:21.627 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: cpu:
```

But when I place the corresponding **.jtl/.csv/.xml** file in the **PerfMon Metrics Collector** listener, CPU & RAM reports is displaying with wrong result. Also both the CPU & RAM results showing same report only.

**RAM Report:**

[image]

**CPU Report:**

[image]

Is there any other solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I found a solution.  Simply add a jtl file on the Perfmon Metrics listener - this file name is for Perfmon only and should have a different name than your jtl file specified in non-gui command line.  It will log when run in non-gui mode.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works fine in non-gui & for distributed testing also